# UPSERT inserts duplicate null entry into table (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to make an upsert trigger on ORACLE via PL/SQL by checking some examples, i am doing fine, i think it is the last step i should only configure. My requirement is that :

A system that will insert to that field will remain one column always null, so i will read column value from another table, then upsert it with inclusion of that value.

> ***d2c_region_locale_config*** holds ***d2c_is_active*** value, so i firstly read that value regarding to locale condition then trigger inserts or updates to table with addition of this value on ***active_for_d2c*** column.(*for update i am using locale and country columns as it is shown on where clause, they are not PK but has not null condition*)

So i've created this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BL_PIM_LOCALE_COUNTRY 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PIM_LOCALE_COUNTRY REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_active_for_d2c INTEGER;
BEGIN
  if :NEW.active_for_d2c is null then
    DELETE from pim_locale_country where active_for_d2c is null;
   select distinct(d2c_isactive) into l_active_for_d2c from d2c_region_locale_config where d2c_locale= :NEW.locale;
   UPDATE pim_locale_country 
    SET locale = :NEW.locale, locale_name = :NEW.locale_name, 
    country = :NEW.country, country_name = :NEW.country_name, isdummy = :NEW.isdummy,
    active_for_d2c = l_active_for_d2c, itextpos = :NEW.itextpos, locale_charset = :NEW.locale_charset,
    fallback_locale = :NEW.fallback_locale, default_for_lang = :NEW.default_for_lang, opeclang = :NEW.opeclang
    where locale = :NEW.locale and country = :NEW.country;
   IF ( sql%notfound ) THEN
      INSERT INTO PIM_LOCALE_COUNTRY (locale,locale_name,country,country_name,isdummy,active_for_d2c,itextpos,locale_charset,fallback_locale,default_for_lang,opeclang)
      VALUES (:NEW.locale, :NEW.locale_name,:NEW.country,:NEW.country_name,:NEW.isdummy,l_active_for_d2c,:NEW.itextpos,:NEW.locale_charset,:NEW.fallback_locale,:NEW.default_for_lang,:NEW.opeclang);
   END IF;
  end if;
END;
```

It currently does the job, reads value and inserts or updates the existing locale-country couple for other values. But critical thing is that, table always has one "null" value(Please check screenshot), even that i run delete statement at the beginning on my trigger. So my question would be how to delete, or how to make this approach on trigger side ?

[image]

Many thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2):

Trigger **before** insert doesn't block insert itself, so you insert that record twice. That is, once your trigger done its work (inserted or updated record), oracle will proceed with insert (or update) using values that stand in NEW record of your trigger. If trigger modifies NEW., it will be stored as you changed it, but if trigger inserts something itself, you can get more records.

You can use **instead of** insert or update triggers, and then oracle will not run its own inserts/updates after trigger finishes.

But more common way for 1-record triggers is to modify fields in NEW, for this case field NEW.d2c_is_active.

It looks like this (possible typos, please check)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BL_PIM_LOCALE_COUNTRY 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON PIM_LOCALE_COUNTRY REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if :NEW.active_for_d2c is null then
    select d2c_isactive 
    into :NEW.active_for_d2c 
    from d2c_region_locale_config 
    where d2c_locale= :NEW.locale and rownum<=1;
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: Actually, i did not get point you've said insert trigger is not blocking but example is before insert trigger, so it couldn't help me unfortunately...

Comment: Well, then change second line, your trigger will be  "instead insert or update ON PIM_LOCALE_COUNTRY REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD"

Comment: Not working... But problem is not that i am selecting value from other table two times, as i've written distinct() at select statement, problem is first statement somehow executed always, and it inserts null value into table... If i add condition not null, trigger can't be executed...

Comment: When i've tried with this way, it is still adding "null" value into table..

Comment: What is the point of `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` anyway?

Comment: This is referring to new row as new, and old row as old, it is not necessary but i did not change that part, but main question is not related to here i think...

Comment: @WilliamRobertson it's for naming convenience. Old row is the one someone wanted to insert, new row is what will be inserted if before-insert trigger works normally. You can call OLD as WHAT_WAS_BEFORE, and you can call NEW as WHAT_IT_WILL_BE, for example. Probably it's like this to avoid possible names clash, since words new and old can be used in local var or column names.

Comment: But `OLD` and `NEW` are the default labels anyway. You are overwriting the defaults with the same values, which seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, it would be better without need to write this nonsense every time.

Comment: Anyway I'm upvoting this answer. The original trigger responds to a null value in an inserted row by inserting a second row with the expected value. Also, confusingly, as it's an `INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger that does its own inserts and updates, it triggers itself so parts of it are run twice. @Hayra the important part of the suggested code is where it assigns a value to `:NEW.active_for_d2c`, which corrects the row currently being inserted, rather than attempting to update previously inserted rows or insert a new row, neither of which are what you really want to do.

Comment: I still did not get, this answer is only including how i can get value from other data, but it is not supporting question's main purpose, to make necessary UPSERT operation, answer only focusses selecting the column from other table.